# Ios Swift Adding UIImageView with a transition / effect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I added multiple UIImageView to a Viewcontroller with Swift Code like that:

```
let imageView_pergament = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pergament.png")!)
...
...
view.addSubview(imageView_pergament)
```

And I would like that they shows up with an transition like effect (pixel in etc.) 
Can someone please help with that did not find a solution yet. Same would be good for removing / hiding them. Maybe, I just need to put a view around it?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, the easy way to perform animation as a view is added or removed is by calling `animate`:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate

One typical strategy is to add the view with `alpha` of 0 and animate the change of `alpha` to 1, thus causing the view to "fade in". However, by animating the `transform` you can achieve vastly more interesting effects if you wish.

Comment: Hello, is this working with an imageview as well? Sorry if that question is to dumb

Comment: Certainly. A view is a view.